# Copy image of an opengl window to a window gdi dc

Tags: windows, opengl, gdi

I have to copy the image of a windows application (form based, not full screen) that is rendered with opengl to a region(panel) of the window of an other application (using GDI functions).

The opengl window is rendered on one monitor with the first graphic card of the system and the destination panel is rendered on an an other monitor, that is controlled by an other graphic card.

Both applications are "third party application". The only information I have are the window handles of both, the opengl application and the destination panel.

I did some tests with Delphi using the "dglOpenGL" unit - but without success. "glReadPixels" always results in an empty data array.

I do not understand how I can get access to an existing rendering context that was created by an other application.

My project is written in Delphi - but if there are hints, code snippets, in C# or C++, that will be helpful, too.

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Default_Framebuffer. If your app is double buffered, you may read from the backbuffer and save the pixels in ram. Take a look at `FBO's`, these are basic objects to render to and read from.

Comment: In concept, to do this across applications, you need something like the BitBlt function (see msdn). However because of the nature capturing opengl rendered windows might lead to a black capture, so unfortunate this leaves from you to the more tedius task, that you need to inject code inside the thirdparty applications and perform the capture with glReadPixels or other relevant api routines from within the thirdparty app, and communicate the results to eachother over interprocess communication i.e. shared memory or perform the GDI calls from there.

Comment: Code injection in the third party application is no option, as I do not have access to the source code. I can create a opengl rendering context based on the DC of the opengl window - and I can draw in this context, too. Depending on how draws last, either my image or the original image is visible. Therefore it seems to me, that two different contexts are created - but I would to get access to the _original_ context with the _original_ frame buffer of the third party application. How can I do this?